# directory link count equals 1

Tags: directory, hard-link

after reading that every directory has at least 2 links (from its parent and from itself), I encountered directories with link count == 1

```
root@ubuntu:~# ll /var/lib/mysql
total 28676
drwx------ 1 mysql mysql      200 Jul 31 18:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root       340 Jul 31 09:34 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql        0 Jul 31 12:57 debian-5.5.flag
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 18874368 Jul 31 13:05 ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  5242880 Jul 31 18:01 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  5242880 Jul 31 12:57 ib_logfile1
drwx------ 1 mysql mysql     1480 Jul 31 12:58 mysql/
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql        6 Jul 31 12:58 mysql_upgrade_info
drwx------ 1 mysql mysql      400 Jul 31 12:58 performance_schema/
```

both links from parent and the directory exist and are functional.
How can this be? is there something Im missing? 
BTW, MySQL working properly :)